# Start and finish lock in different methods

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, parallel-processing

I would like to - for obscure reasons thou shall not question - start a lock in a method, and end it in another. Somehow like:

```
object mutex = new object();

void Main(string[] args)
{
    lock (mutex)
    {
        doThings();
    }
}
```

Would have the same behaviour as:

```
object mutex = new object();

void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo();
    doThings();
    Bar();
}

void Foo()
{
    startLock(mutex);
}

void Bar()
{
    endlock(mutex);
}
```

The problem is that the lock keyword works in a block syntax, of course. I'm aware that locks are not meant to be used like this, but I'm more than open to the creative and hacky solutions of S/O. :)

Comment: "for obscure reasons thou shall not question". You looking to get downvoted? Sets a bad tone.

Comment: @Oded: I was looking for a humoristic tone, sorry. I simply want to avoid the conversations on good design, as I know this is not, and am fully aware of this fact. I'd rather see creative solutions and hacks, which is why the question was tagged with `hacks`.

Comment: I am fine with people using humor here, but "thou shall not question" just sounds a off putting and elitist.

Comment: @Oded: Apparently, there *was* a way that was meant to fulfill my needs (see Alex Aza's answer). In that case, that part was inappropriate, and I apologize again.

Comment: @Oded, @Lazlo: "thou shalt not" sound humorous to me.  It all seemed a polite way to ask people not to focus on that part of the OP's question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
private readonly object syncRoot = new object();

void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo();
    doThings();
    Bar();
}

void Foo()
{
    Monitor.Enter(syncRoot);
}

void Bar()
{
    Monitor.Exit(syncRoot);
}
```

[**Edit**]

When you use `lock`, this is what happening under the hood in .NET 4:

```
bool lockTaken = false;
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(syncRoot, ref lockTaken);

    // code inside of lock
}
finally
{
    if (lockTaken)
        Monitor.Exit(_myObject);
}
```

Comment: Well, that was much easier than expected.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx:

"The `lock` keyword calls `Enter` at the start of the block and `Exit` at the end of the block."

Comment: The `lock` statement is just syntactic sugar for `Monitor.Enter(x) try{ /*work*/ } finally{ Monitor.Exit(x) }`.

Comment: I feel so bad for not looking at the doc. I assumed it was static. Oh well, sorry. At least this thread will go in search engines results.

Comment: @Joel In .net 4 it uses a different construct to avoid problems with thread abortion.

Comment: And obviously this code will not cope with exceptions at all(With thread abortion being especially evil).

Comment: @CodesInChaos So I guess the next logical question is how do we cope with exceptions then?

Comment: @Nate If you're willing to ignore thread abortion, you can use `using`. If you need to support thread abortion, you'll need a `try`...`finally` pattern similar to what `lock` generates under the hood.